# Error "invalid types 'float [100][float]' for array subscript"

Tags: c, fft, ifft

I have copied the whole code below and commented on the line I am getting the error.

I am trying to test a iDFT algorithm I found online but I cannot get it to compile can anyone help me with the following error message when I try to compile?

> error: invalid types 'float [100][float]' for array subscript

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

 int main()
 {
  float static X[100],X_Real[100],X_Imag[100];
  float k,n,N;

  printf("\t\t\t Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform(IDFT)"); 
  printf("\n\n Enter the length of DFT N=");
  scanf("%f",&N);
  printf("\n Enter the real and imaginary parts of X(k) as follows:\n\n"

 "X(k) =Real{X(k)} Img{X(k)} \n" );

  for(k=0;k<N;k++)
 {
  printf("X(%1.0f)=",k);                 
  scanf("%f %f",&X_Real[k],&X_Imag[k]);  // This is where I get the error
 }

 for(n=0;n<N;n++)
 {
  X[n]=0;
  for(k=0;k<N;k++)
  {
   X[n]=X[n]+X_Real[k]*cos((2*M_PI*k*n)/N)-X_Imag[k]*sin((2*M_PI*k*n)/N);
  }
  X[n]=X[n]/N;
 }

 printf("\n\n The sequence x(n) is as follows...");
 for(n=0;n<N;n++)
 {
  printf("\n\n X(%1.0f)=%3.6f",n,X[n]);
 }

 getch();
}
```

Comment: An array index *must* be an integral type ([6.5.2.1/1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)); using a `float` as an index is a constraint violation.

Comment: Hi John Bode, Thanks for the rapid response, I understand the error now. But now my question is "is there a way to make the array index act like an int variable even though it needs to stay as a float?" I know I read about something called typecasting but I am not sure how to utilise this as I am still a newbie to coding and programming.

Comment: Hi @JohnBode , managed to fix my issue. I just typecasted the array index's in to int and everything seems to be working fine! thank you!

Comment: You can use a cast like so: `X[ (int) n ]`.  However, be aware that a cast like this simply truncates the fractional portion - it essentially rounds towards 0.  For example, `(int) 1.9999999` => `1`.  If you need to round to the nearest integer, you'll have to get more creative.  If you *know* `n` is always non-negative, `(int) (n + 0.5)` will do in a pinch.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBode, that is exactly what i did, was not aware of the truncation though, i shall follow your tip! thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong: `k, n,` and `N` must be declared as integers. You can't access an array with a float index (what's the 2.34th value in this array)?

Comment: Hi Lee,

Thank you for you answer! it has helped me understand the problem.

But is there a way to make the variable act like an int variable just so I can use it as an index?

Comment: Hi @Lee Daniel Crocker , managed to fix my issue. I just typecasted the array index's in to int and everything seems to be working fine! thank you!